# Ubuntu Server monitor goes to sleep in 10 minutes

Tags: ubuntu, power-management, x-server

Is there a possibility to disable the monitor sleep in Ubuntu server 14.04?
After 10 minutes my monitor goes to sleep.
I've already tried several options, from https://superuser.com/questions/152347/change-linux-console-screen-blanking-behavior/154388#154388

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this from the console, as root:

```
# setterm -blank 0 >> /etc/issue
```

This will add the escape sequence to prevent console blanking to the file `/etc/issue` which is displayed before the "login: " prompt. Thus the blanking is effectively permanently disabled.

If you're leaving the screen running X, then the above won't have any effect. In that case running `xset -dpms; xset s off` may help, unless you're also running some other screensaver program, or if your desktop environment has its own ideas of powersaving/screen blanking/etc. so then you should investigate its settings in those areas.

Comment: I tried this answer but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: did you log out after doing this?

Comment: Yes, i rebooted the system. I also added the line myself to /etc/issue but that didn't solve my problem either.

Comment: Ah, are you leaving it at the GUI, i.e. the X display? Try switching to the console via ctrl-alt-F1 and leaving it there.

Comment: I'm using xserver to display a webpage and thats when the monitor goes to sleep.

Comment: I've edited my answer to address the issue when running X.

Comment: Thx for the update but i now get "unable to open display "" " 2 times

Comment: Do this from an xterm and don't use `sudo` or similar i.e. run it as the normal user.

Comment: I don't get any messages now, but the screen keeps blanking after 10 mins.

Comment: Then you need to check your desktop environment's power settings, as I mentioned earlier. http://blog.tordeu.com/?p=292 may help; I don't use gnome myself.

Comment: I just installed an ubuntu  14.04 server with xorg and firefox thats showing a website that needs to be always on.

Comment: When the server starts, he also starts a init.d file to start this certain website.
The file looks like this :
"startx -e firefox "http://www.mywebsite.com"

Looking at the answers i added an extra line "xset -dpms; xset s blank"
but this didn't solve my problem.

Comment: The `startx` keeps running as long as the firefox is active; so the `xset` is never executed. Try using `startx -e sh -c 'xset -dpms; xset s off; firefox mywebsite.com'` (note *not* `xset s blank` as that forces the blank!)

Comment: Now i've got the following message,                                                   Loading extension GLX                                                                            Xinit : connection to server lost

Comment: Maybe it's best to switch the blanking off in the xorg config; see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Power_Management_Signaling or http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=136543

Comment: Hi, i solved my problem using porteus-kiosk. Fast and easy to setup.